# Создать php-бота для биржи без использования API

Tags: php, бот, exchange, криптография

Передо мной стоит задача создать торгового бота для биржи Hotbit. Проблема в том, что Hotbit даёт доступ к API лишь узкому кругу лиц, в список которых ваш покорный слуга не проходит по критериям. Говорят, пока идет тест и отладка, но сколько оно продлится - без понятия. Какие есть варианты написать торгового бота без использования API? Язык программирования - php

Comment: Ну определенно нужно как то с помощью php эмулировать действия пользователя, обходить капчу если она есть, вникать в запросы которые кидаются на сервер. Но в этом случае легче устроитья к ним на работу и внедриться в доверие  :D

Comment: Очевидно, что никаких.

Comment: Ну, говорить, что брось эту затею не буду, хотя надо, но посмотрим в сторону Selenium (c PHP я его не юзал, ток с Go), но думаю он и под слоника имеется, поиграешься, не получится, за то с пользой.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, исходя из комментов и собственных наблюдений было выяснено, что у этой задачи только два пути на реализацию. Эмуляция браузера или писать на питоне с использованием куки вместо API ключа.
https://githubplus.com/sjoerd1999/Hotbit_API